# Wbadmin fullbackup to an external HDD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-server-backup, wbadmin

I need to backup a Windows Server 2008 R2 every day. The backup should contain some folders (With subfolders) on an internal HDD and the system state.

```
WBADMIN START BACKUP -backupTarget:b: -include:d:\Company,d:\Profiles,d:\Users -systemState -vssFull -quiet
```

It works, but its only an incremental backup. How can I force wbadmin to create a full-backup?

Comment: Is it to the same hdd every day?

Comment: Yes, he creates an backup every to the external hdd B:

Comment: Ok in which case this is how windows backup works. The difference is unlike traditional incremental backups where a corrupt backup might mean you could not restore, Windows backup doesn't have that problem.

Comment: And what about restoring? For example I need to restore a backup from 2 weeks ago so I have to restore every backup until the backup I need to restore. Because an incremental backup only contains changed files.

Comment: No when you restore you just pick the date and issue one command to restore to that date. There is a catalog of what changed when